# Adding external plugins to TinyMCE in django

Tags: javascript, python, django, tinymce

I have configured TinyMCE in my django project. But I want to add some external plugins to this editor. I have found many plugins [here](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/) but I don't know how to add it. I searched on internet but it was not of much use. It will be great if somebody can take an external plugin form the site mentioned above and explain how it is added(explain the folder in which js file has to be added and where to create the folder).

My TinyMCE configuration: #added these in settings

```
TINYMCE_JS_ROOT = '/media/tiny_mce/'
TINYMCE_JS_URL = "tiny_mce/tiny_mce_src.js"
TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG = {
    'plugins': "table,spellchecker,paste,searchreplace",
    'theme': "advanced",
}
TINYMCE_SPELLCHECKER = True
```

url.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url,include
from django.contrib import admin
from blog import views
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^markdown/', include('django_markdown.urls')),
    url(r'^home/$',views.home,name='home'),
    url(r'(?P<post_id>[0-9]+)/$',views.post,name='post'),
    url(r'^tinymce/', include('tinymce.urls')),
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the external plugins into your django tinymce plugion directory and you can add them using the tinymce plugin configuration parameter.

Comment: Can you improve this answer by telling us where we can find those downloadable plugin files?

Comment: sorry, i cant remember anymore